# Console.ReadLine() passed to C# event

Tags: events, console, system.reactive, readline

I'm learning RX and would like to use Console.ReadLine as a source for observable sequences.

I know that I can create "IEnumerable" using "yield return", but for my concrete use case I've decided to create a C# event, so that potentially many observers will be able to share the same keyboard input.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    private delegate void OnNewInputLineHandler(string line);

    private static event OnNewInputLineHandler OnNewInputLineEvent = _ => {};

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run((Action) GetInput);

        var input = ConsoleInput();
        input.Subscribe(s=>Console.WriteLine("1: " + s));

        Thread.Sleep(30000);
    }

    private static void GetInput()
    {
        while (true)
            OnNewInputLineEvent(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    private static IObservable<string> ConsoleInput()
    {
        return Observable.Create<string>(
        (IObserver<string> observer) =>
        {
            OnNewInputLineHandler h = observer.OnNext;
            OnNewInputLineEvent += h;
            return Disposable.Create(() => { OnNewInputLineEvent -= h; });
        });
    }
}
```

My problem - when I run the GetInput method as it is shown above, the very first input line is not sent to the sequence (but it is sent to the event handler).

However, if I replace it with the following version, everything works as expected:

```
private static void GetInput()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var s = Console.ReadLine();
        OnNewInputLineEvent(s);
    }
}
```

Could someone shed some light on why this might happen?

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to make life difficult for yourself. There is almost always a way to make things simple with Rx. It's just a matter of learning to think more functionally rather than procedurally.

This is all you need:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subscription = ConsoleInput().Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine("1: " + s));
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        subscription.Dispose();
    }

    private static IObservable<string> ConsoleInput()
    {
        return
            Observable
                .FromAsync(() => Console.In.ReadLineAsync())
                .Repeat()
                .Publish()
                .RefCount()
                .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default);
    }
}
```

This lets multiple subscribers share the one input through the `.Publish().RefCount()`. And the `.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default)` pushes the subscription out to a new thread - without it you block on a subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Yet it does not answer my question - why one version works:
        var s = Console.ReadLine();
        OnNewInputLineEvent(s);
while the other looses the first notification:
     OnNewInputLineEvent(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: @Natan - I'm going to guess a race condition, but it's hard to prove. The IL generated is so similar - one just stores the string in a variable first. It might just be taking a few commands longer. Seems a little dodgy to me.

Comment: That was my first thought too. I also browsed the IL code and couldn't discern why this makes a difference. But if it were a race condition it would not be so consistent! It is the same behavior in Debug and Release versions and if I run directly or in the debugger. I guess I'll need to build RX and try to debug, but I'm not sure it's worth the effort.

Comment: Nice answer. I think the first line in the `Main` has an extra bracket and is missing a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

If you move `Task.Run((Action) GetInput);` to after the subscription your code will work as desired. This is because in your original version, the first call of `OnNewInputEvent(Console.ReadLine())` is run before you've hooked OnNewInputLineEvent to the `observer.OnNext`.

Comment: Correct! The difference between the 2 versions is that in `var s = ...` version, GetInput hangs waiting for the input and the subscription happens before any reference to the event field is made. In the short version `event(Console.ReadLine())`, the compiler first copies the event field's value (at this moment the value has only one non-Rx subscriber) and then calls `ReadLine()`. Even though the subscription happens before the first input line is entered, the value used by the compiler is the previous one.